# How can I print out a series of number starting at 1 less than x and ending at 0?

Tags: java, for-loop

When I run this, I don't get any input at all? What's wrong?

```
int x = inp.nextInt();

//write your code below

     for(int reverse = x - 1 ; reverse >= x ; reverse--) { 
          System.out.print(reverse); 
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should decrease the value `reverse` until it reaches 0.  If you chose `reverse >= x` the loop will never complete.

```
for(int reverse = x - 1; reverse >= 0; reverse--) { 
  System.out.print(reverse); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your for loop

```
for (int reverse = x - 1 ; reverse >= x ; reverse--) {...}
```

You start with reverse being x - 1. Therefore, the second condition is by default false. So nothing happens.